# MySQLでカラムに対して後からUNIQUE制約を追加したいのですが、UNIQUEキー名？ について

Tags: mysql

**MySQLカラムに対して後からUNIQUE制約を追加したいです。**
下記コードで動作すると思われるのですが、uk_name 部分について

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD UNIQUE uk_name (column1, column2);
```

---

**Q1.この名前は何ですか？**
・ユニークキー名？
・インデックスキー名？
・[公式サイトで ALTER TABLE 構文](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/alter-table.html)を確認してみたのですが、ドキュメントの見方が良く分かりませんでした

```
  | ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]]
        UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY] [index_name]
        [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_option] ...
```

---

**Q2.この名前に使用できる文字は何ですか？**
使用不可な文字 や 文字数制限 などありますか？

---

**Q3.この名前を後から使用しますか？**
・この名前を使用する場面を思いつかないのですが、ここに付与した名前を使用して後から呼び出したりしますか？
・UNIQUE制約のありなしで条件分岐する際に必要？？　忘れないよう控えておいた方が良いですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. index_name なので「インデックス名」でいいと思います。5.6 の日本語マニュアルにもそう書かれています。
2. インデックス名等の識別子についてはここに書かれています。 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/identifiers.html
3. drop index や select の use 等で使用されます。